# How can I make a loop that will wait an action first to continue, in android?

Tags: android, loops

I'm trying to create a quiz test. In the questions form I make 3 buttons that when the user click the answer. It restarts the same layout and the java class, so it appears the next question. Well this way is not so good, as it's painful to call the same layout again and again. So how I change the code so it change the questions in the same layout 20 times? I tried `while` function but it does not work as it dont wait to press a button to continue to next question (if there is a command to wait from user to make an action to continue the while loop, it would work). Here is my code:

```
package dv.qtest.dvyzual;

import java.util.Random;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.database.Cursor;  
import android.media.MediaPlayer;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;   
import android.widget.Button;   
import android.widget.TextView;

public class startGame extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startgame); 
        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct);

        AnyDBAdapter eventsData = new AnyDBAdapter(getBaseContext());
        eventsData.open();
        myMenu.question = myMenu.question +1;
        String qq = getRandomNumber();  
        Cursor c = eventsData.ExampleSelect(qq);
        this.startManagingCursor(c);
        eventsData.close();         final String h = c.getString(5);        setQuestions(c);

        final Button r1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        r1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {             public void onClick(View v) {
                if ("1".equals(h)) {
                    r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);
                    myMenu.score = myMenu.score + 1;
                    mp2.start();
                }
                else {
                    r1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneowrong);
                }
                finish();
                if (myMenu.question == 20) {  
            startActivity(new Intent("dv.qtest.dvyzual.QuizTestActivity.ENDQUIZGAME"));}
                else {
                startActivity(new Intent("dv.qtest.dvyzual.QuizTestActivity.STARTQUIZGAME"));
                }
                            }       });         final Button r2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        r2.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {             public void onClick(View v) {
                if ("2".equals(h)) {
                    r2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);
                    myMenu.score = myMenu.score + 1;
                }
                else {
                    r2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneowrong);
                }
                finish();
                if (myMenu.question == 20) {startActivity(new Intent("dv.qtest.dvyzual.QuizTestActivity.ENDQUIZGAME"));}
                else {startActivity(new Intent("dv.qtest.dvyzual.QuizTestActivity.STARTQUIZGAME"));}            }       });
                final Button r3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
        r3.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {             public void onClick(View v) {
                if ("3".equals(h)) {
                    r3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneocorrect);
                    myMenu.score = myMenu.score + 1;
                    mp2.start();
                }
                else {
                    r3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonneowrong);
                }
                finish();
                if (myMenu.question == 20) {startActivity(new Intent("dv.qtest.dvyzual.QuizTestActivity.ENDQUIZGAME"));}
                else {startActivity(new Intent("dv.qtest.dvyzual.QuizTestActivity.STARTQUIZGAME"));}            }       });
        }

    private String getRandomNumber(){

        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 49;
        n = generator.nextInt(n) +1;
        String n1 = ""+n;
        return n1;
    }

    private void setQuestions(Cursor c) {
                TextView rscore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.q1);      rscore.setText("Score: " + myMenu.score + "             Question: "
+ myMenu.question);

        TextView r0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);       r0.setText(c.getString(1));
                Button r1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);      r1.setText(c.getString(2));
                Button r2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);      r2.setText(c.getString(3));
                Button r3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);      r3.setText(c.getString(4));
            }        }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Object Oriented programming and its differences from Procedural programming?

Comment: Well, to be honest as i am new to this language, i am not so familiar and maybe i do some big mistakes while i am coding. Do you see many mistakes that i have to fix?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't took the time to look at your code yet, I just recognize the way I used to think before I started coding in java (which was my first object oriented programming language) in your question.  your code might be ok but its important to understand the way to think about coding and solving problems in OOP. you dont freeze your code  in any way in android (actually the os will kill your app if it does) it needs to keep on going.

Comment: you are right it's a little chaotic at start. well yes that code working but with wrong way, i want just to refresh the questions when i click on buttons without restart the layout and all code, as it cause some problems

Answer (score 1):

Well I won't response your answer... because you are in the wrong way to start Android development.

You'll have to learn some concepts of OOP... read in order :

http://www.osnews.com/story/6788

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

And also this to have a good code implementation :

http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Then... look the android samples, there are very good samples, they are in :

%AndroidSDK%/samples/

Also, you will have to understand the android architecture and the android running :

[image: Android system architecture]

[image]

Comment: Other things to take into account: Android is an Event-Driven architecture. OOP (and even Java) does not necessarily require Event Driven models, so it may also be advantageous to study Event Driven programming and its concepts.

Comment: @Fuzzi : Good point!

NeoX : To be clear, it's not to be wicked. But if you continue in this way you will loose your time. Follow the android view's tutorials :

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html